# Twitter gem for Ruby: How to safely iterate over friends of someone who has A LOT of friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, iteration, rate-limiting

I'm confused about the `friends` method in the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).  I see that [Twitter::REST::FriendsAndFollowers#friends](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/rest/friends_and_followers.rb) uses a [GET friends/list](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list) request and the `cursor_from_response_with_user` method.

The documentation for `GET friends/list` says that requests are limited to 20 users. I assume this means that 20 friends will be returned per request. But, say I am following 22 people and I use the following:

```
twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new { [my credentials here] }
twitter_client.friends
```

This returns an array of all 22 friends. I didn't do anything to mess with cursors, so why am I getting all 22? On to my main question...

In my app, when someone imports their friends, I'm iterating over them and creating some other records. Something like this

```
twitter_client.friends.each do |friend|
  SomeModel.do_what_you_need_to_with(friend)
  AnotherModel.do_something_else_with(friend)
end
```

Let's say someone has 5001 Twitter friends. (Impressive!) I'm thinking this is going to be a problem with rate limiting, etc. What's the safest way to get *all* the friends, and iterate over all of them?

I've tried to figuring out the gem's documentation on cursors, but the fact that `friends` returned 22 results is throwing me off...

Comment: i have worked on similar kind of feature. but for the rate limit, it's completely depend on twitter api, you can do nothing. What you can do is just periodically run a rask to fetch friends.

Answer (score 0):

The 20 that you mention is the number of users per page returned by the API. The gem will iterate over all pages, so it will return as many users as possible within the rate limit.

As how to handle the rate limiting, it's up to you. There's an example [here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) that will just put the process to sleep for a while and then retry. Another option is to just quit the app and run it again in a few minutes with something like cron, but it obviously depends on your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question.  I ran into the same issue.

I can see how iterating over *ALL* friends is a feature. However, if you are only interested in the first 20 friends , here's how to ***not*** request any more friends:

```
twitter_client.friends.to_h[ :users ]
```

Since friends request returns 20, this may not be so useful. If you want friend_ids or follower_ids, the API will return up to 5,000. For many use cases 5,000 is plenty.

```
twitter_client.friends.to_h[ :ids ]
```